# Hibernate Annotation Mapping Problems

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations

I am currently experiencing a problem where a call to retrieve a menu structure from my database and render as json is taking too long to run (8 seconds)

On further analysis its a problem with my Hibernate annotations - i have specified the annotations to load lazily where possible but when i enable hibernate show sql - i see alot of queries running that could slow down my operations.

The data I am returning is purely text - no clobs or blobs or anything fancy so that makes it more confusing for me

If anyone has time to look at my annotations and perhaps identify the problem or provide me feedback on where I can improve - it would be much appreciated

A link to the code relevant to the problem is as follows
https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0BxV2AtLUezzGUUptVEROZVFzQ00&usp=sharing

There is a readme file in there with some further details

Any help is greatly appreciated

Thanking you in advance

Comment: Your question is not specific enough, see [asking a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You should provide an extract of the code where you think the problem is, with all context infos that may help. For instance in the files provided, I don't see how your service uses the beans.

Comment: Hi Abbe - I understand your concerns about this question sorry. I put the code on google drive as there was a good chunk of it and didnt know what to do. My service basically just loads those beans from the db and returns to the controller to render in json